# Sun Movement (Y/Z movement)

Tags: c++, axis, game-development

I'm wondering the best way to simulate a sunrise/sunset on the y and z axis.  At the moment it does what I want but is moving too fast (say every 3 seconds it's already completed an entire sun path and is already moving in reverse back to the origin).

I know this has to do with seconds variable combined with sin and cos, as this function is called and moves the light's position every frame.  Basically I want it to be linked to my game's timer of 50:

- 50 seconds it's sunrise
- 25 seconds it's noon
- 0 seconds it's sunset/game over

Currently I have:

```
lightPosition = Point_E3d(0,
                          std::abs(100 *std::cos(seconds)),
                          -100 * std::sin(seconds));
```

Wondering what's the correct code format to achieve this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just simple trigonometry. The period (Time until the function repeats) of sine(x * n) and cosine(x * n) are both 2*pi / n. In this case, n = 1, so the period is 6.28, meaning one full day (and night) will last 6.28 seconds. If you want to increase the period, multiply your `seconds` argument by a number smaller than one. A little bit of algebra shows that:

```
period of sin(x * n) = 2*pi / n
period of sin(.1256 * x) = 2*pi / .1256 = 6.28 / 0.1256 = 50
```

Therefore, take sine and cosine of seconds * 0.1256, rather than just seconds.

```
lightPosition = Point_E3d(0,
                          std::abs(100 *std::cos(seconds * 0.1256 )),
                          -100 * std::sin(seconds * 0.1256));
```

Note that this is also including the night time. If you want just the 12 hour day time period to last 50 seconds, multiply by half of 0.1256, aka 0.0628.

Comment: @Psychosupreme try flipping sin and cos. Does that work?

Comment: Ya it did, deleted the comment cuz I figured it out right before you responded I guess lol